# Listening for Events in a VB.Net Script?

Tags: vb.net, scripting, cad

I am in need of a solution, and I am not quite sure I have enough knowledge to properly ask the question, so please bear with me. I am working with a CAD application with it's own API which supports the .NET Framework 4.5. I wanted to develop some customized functionality for the application using VB.NET, but because of work restrictions I am not allowed to install custom programs or run custom executables. I am however allowed to utilize the CAD applications scripting environment  (which also supports the  .NET Framework). I am limited in what I can achieve with scripting because as far I know I can't listen for an event in a script, because the scripts run time ends so quickly. Is there a way to extend the run time of a script until certain events occur? If anybody is curious, the CAD application I am using is called Siemens NX. Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe a question you should ask whoever wrote this API ?

Comment: Yea, I tried contacting the company technical support, and the API does not have any events I can utilize to do what I want. I was hoping to make the script run and pause execution until it received Excel triggered events, such as the Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how far this answer help you.

When you do not have events to listen, try to depend on return variables and using assert statements (or at least if statements).

I mean, if something happens then only go to next, which is a very traditional way.

Also, if you want to prolong the run time of script you can use some thing like "sleep" or "delay" statements (may be milli seconds as input).

I mean if some thing is happening (control by a variable), "sleep" till that action is complete.

Or check for the action complete status in a infinite while loop and exit, when it is done.

In simple terms, traditional way of doing things helps in your situation.

Comment: Well, the infinite for loop is certainly an idea. It obviously isn't an ideal solution but what I am trying to do is more of a hack anyway. I will give that a try. Thank you.